# Equivalent of Flex DataBinding using Pure Actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

When Flex Sees Something Like This:

```
<mx:Label text="Hello {MyVar} World!"/>
```

It Must Translate That Somehow Into ActionScript.  But What If I Need To Do Something Similar, At Runtime.  How Can I Accomplish What DYNAMICALLY?  WHEN I DO NOT KNOW THE CONTENTS OF THE BINDING TEMPLATE.

In ActionScript it would need it to look *something* like this:

```
public function CustomDynamicBinding(StringToBind:String):Label {
  // *EXAMPLES* Of StringToBind:
  //    "Hello {MyVar} World!"
  //    "Product: {name} ${price}.00"
  //    "{data.label}, {data.description}"
  // I've Written It This Way Because I DO NOT KNOW The Exact Text To Be Bound At Design Time.
  [Bindable]
    var Lab:Label=new Label();
    Lab.text=???
    return(Lab);
}
```

How can I accomplish this kind of "Dynamic" binding... Where I **don't know** the value of "StringToBind" until runtime?  For the purposes of this question we can assume that I do know that any variable(s) mentioned in "StringToBind", are guaranteed to exist at runtime.

I already realize there are much more straightforward ways to accomplish this exact thing STATICALLY, and using only Flex/MXML.  It's important for my project though that I understand how this could be accomplished without MXML.

Doing This:
    lab.text = stringToBind.replace("{myVar}", str);

Will NOT work because this simply assigns ONCE the value of "{myVar}" - (which may not even BE the variable referenced in "stringToBind"!!) to the label, and does not take into account when and if myVar changes!  Wouldn't I need to somehow use something Like  bindProperty?

Comment: Joshua, I hope this is what you want, more or less:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081229/flex-actionscript-how-to-change-property-label-of-all-buttons/3084992#3084992

Answer (score 3):

Use [BindingUtils.bindSetter](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html#bindSetter%28%29)

```
var stringToBind:String = "Hello {myVar} World!";
[Bindable]
var myVar:String = 'Flex';
var lab:Label = new Label();
BindingUtils.bindSetter(labelValue, this, "myVar");
function set labelValue(str:String):void
{
  lab.text = "Hello " + str + " World!";
  //or if you want it dynamic
  lab.text = stringToBind.replace("{myVar}", str);
}
```

Note that this is not pure ActionScript in its strict sense as data binding itself is a Flex concept; this is just MXML-less syntax of doing it. You're still using Flex binding internally - but again, use of `Label` alone makes if *Flexy*

Comment: You have hard coded the "StringToBind".  The whole POINT is that what's being bound is not know at design time.

Comment: The label text will also not change when myVar changes, if done this way.

Comment: @Joshua Did you even try this? Label text will change when `myVar` changes. And about hard coding - this is not as hard coded as `<mx:Label text="Hello {MyVar} World!"/>` is hard coded. You can always update `stringToBind` at runtime and use my second method.

Comment: @Joshua You're missing the point. The point was to use bindSetter to set up a function that will execute when the value of a property of your choosing changes. Whatever you do in that function is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
private function _BindingSource_bindingsSetup():Array
{
    var result:Array = [];

    result[0] = new mx.binding.Binding(this,
        function():String
        {
            var result:* = "Hello " + (MyVar) + " World!";
            return (result == undefined ? null : String(result));
        },
        null,
        "_BindingSource_Label1.text"
        );


    return result;
}
```

It's only a part of generated code. Feel free to add `-keep-generated-actionscript` parameter to compiler options and read all generated ActionScript in `bin-debug\generated`.

Comment: You have hard-coded "Hello World" and "MyVar"...  How does this help me?

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure: shameless self promotion

The [BindageTools](http://code.google.com/p/bindage-tools/) library provides an intuitive builder API for setting up bindings in ActionScript.